# Actual word for "Broadity"?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, synonyms

I'm looking for a single word that explains how broad or widespread something can be. Since "broadity" or "widespreadity" aren't real words, are there any viable alternatives?

Comment: the *-ness* suffix is productive with *broad* and *widespread*...

Comment: Would "breadth" work for you?

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what I'm looking for. I answered my own question about 10 seconds before you posted this :)

Comment: what are you asking?? broadity widepreadity ??? If some thing is very big just use "broad" for ex- "broad-minded" or "giant" for ex. "the giant" or "great" for ex. "the great escape".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Breadth" is actually the word I'm looking for.

Comment: Doesn't _spread_ convey the sense better?